# ffmpeg using Single image and an audio file, but output video is not seek-able ( only resumes from 0:00, even if seeked ahead )

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

Using Ffmpeg on Android to make a video from Single image merged with an Audio file, it works but the output video is not seeking to any time stamps 
ex - always starts from 0:00, on seeking the video ahead it just restarts the whole video from start.

The command I used is -

```
 -y  -framerate  30  -i  "+ImagePath+"  -i  "+AudioPath+"  -vsync  vfr  -c:v  libx264  -codec:a  copy  -pix_fmt  yuv420p  -crf  23  "+OutputVideoPath
```

can this be due to single frame only? (one image in video) 
if so what can be used to convert a single image to seekable video.

Comment: Is your audio file AAC format? If not then try without `-codec:a  copy`. Just try as : `-y  -framerate  30  -i  "+ImagePath+"  -i  "+AudioPath+"  -c:v  libx264  -pix_fmt  yuv420p  -crf  18  "+OutputVideoPath` also check your ending `"+OutputVideoPath` is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: @VC.One Used the query without `-codec:copy` and it still couldn't produce the desired results. plus it made the process really slow. Help please I'm stuck.

Comment: MP4 is expected to have an AAC audio codec. Make sure your input is AAC format (then can just `c:a copy`) or else it will convert from MP3 to AAC (takes time). Anytime in mixed A+V data, if issues like frozen video or not seeking it mean sound part is causing issue. Even if you choose MP3 make sure it's **stereo**, at **16-bit** and sample rate of  **44**.1khz or **48**khz. I will test your command when I'm on FFmpeg later

Comment: yes, I am using mp3 Audio files (stereo & 44.1Khz). I can Add ffmpeg logs if that will help you understand better?

Comment: [link](https://paste.ee/p/0TldV) This is the complete Log of FFmpeg process. Thanks again

Comment: See if my Answer gives you correct output (video is seekable, etc).

Comment: @VC.One I tried your command, it shows a bunch of error lines. I've attached on your Answer below.Sir, please check

Answer (score 1):

This command will work to make a seekable MP4 (using input from image file and MP3 audio).

```
ffmpeg -y -i AUDIO.file -f image2 -loop 1 -r 2 -i IMAGE.file -shortest -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -framerate 30 -preset veryfast -movflags +faststart OUTPUT.mp4
```

Just replace `AUDIO.file` and `IMAGE.file`and `OUTPUT.mp4` with your custom file names.

**Try this in your Android code:**

```
-y -i "+AudioPath+" -f image2 -loop 1 -r 2 -i "+ImagePath+" -shortest -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -framerate 30 -preset veryfast -movflags +faststart "+OutputVideoPath+"
```

Try setting up your code like this:

```
"-y -i "+AudioPath+" -f image2 -loop 1 -r 2 -i "+ImagePath+" -shortest -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -framerate 30 -preset veryfast -movflags +faststart "+OutputVideoPath
```

Comment: Change the input `-r` to `-framerate` and the output `-framerate` to `-r`.

Comment: @VC.One   Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size        
Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size                                  
Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.                                                                            Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!

Comment: I used FFmpeg on desktop command line and I had **no errors**. Is it possible your shown code example should have started as : `"-y -i "+AudioPath` etc...? **See the update**. If still got error, then please show complete Log of this new command.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I'm successfully using
`ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i IMAGE6.jpg -i AUDIO.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset:v veryfast -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune:v stillimage -r 30 -vf scale=-1:1080 -c:a copy -shortest VIDEO.mp4`
but unfortunately the resulting file becomes about 6 tmes larger than the audio input!
Any idea how to avoid that?